# Over 300 photos in gridview [Android]

Tags: android, gridview, xamarin

What is the best way to store over 300 photos in gridview? Is there any way to make pagination or something? When i put a lot of thumbnails gridview scroll is very slow.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a GridView as this loads all the images at once, regardless of whether they're visible or not.

You need to use a RecyclerView (or ListView, though I don't recommend it as RecyclerView is superior), so your Adapter handles the data to display based on what's visible.

[RecyclerView docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nice plugin in Xamarin, U can use this in Xamarin.Android

[FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading)

I am using this in my app & it store as per you need.